# Нахождение общих слов в списке (проверка на вхождение)

Tags: python

Добрый день, друзья! Задача следующая, - найти общие слова в двух строках, то есть :

```
checkio("hello,world", "hello,earth") == "hello"
```

или

```
checkio("one,two,three", "four,five,six") == ""
```

Код для решения данной задачи я написал. Прошу судить СТРОГО.
Данный код проверку не проходит.

```
def checkio(first, second):
list_one = first.split(',')
list_two = second.split(',')
list_new = []

for word in list_one:
    if word in list_two:
        list_new.append(word)

return list_new

if __name__ == '__main__':
    assert checkio("hello,world", "hello,earth") == "hello", "Hello"
    assert checkio("one,two,three", "four,five,six") == "", "Too different"
    assert checkio("one,two,three", "four,five,one,two,six,three") == "one,three,two", "1 2 3"
```

Не проходит код, потому как возвращается список в форме `['hello']` , а ожидается возвращение в форме `"hello"`.

Я понимаю, что мой вопрос, вероятнее всего, абсолютно элементарный, но увы, не могу найти ответа на него, прошу Вашей помощи.

Так же, прошу показать мне, как можно "по-нормальному", записать данные строки кода (уверен, что их можно написать по-человечески, а не как у меня):

```
list_one = first.split(',')
list_two = second.split(',')
```

и

```
for word in list_one:
    if word in list_two:
        list_new.append(word)
```

Большое спасибо.

Comment: а что вы ожидаете в качестве результата: `checkio('one,two,three', 'two,one')`?

Comment: у вас вопрос как из `['hello']` получить `'hello'`? Откуда вы assert взяли? (конкретную ссылку на checkio.org, если возможно)  Вы хотите узнать логику, которая объяснит почему ответ `"one,three,two"`, а не другие пять вариантов?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы общие слова найти в двух списках:

```
common_words = set(list_one).intersection(list_two)
```

Чтобы `assert` заработал, просто отсортируйте слова и объедините через запятую:

```
result = ','.join(sorted(common_words))
```

Answer (score 2):

я бы так сделал:

```
In [107]: def checkio(l1, l2):
     ...:     return list(set(l1.split(',')) & set(l2.split(',')))
     ...:

In [108]: checkio("one,two,three", "four,five,six")
Out[108]: []

In [109]: checkio("hello,world", "hello,earth")
Out[109]: ['hello']
```

вот чуть более универсальный вариант, который может сравнивать вне зависимости от регистра (внимание возвращает список слов, приведенных к нижнему регистру)

```
In [110]: def checkio(l1, l2, case_insensitive=False):
     ...:     if case_insensitive:
     ...:         return list(set(l1.lower().split(',')) & set(l2.lower().split(',')))
     ...:     else:
     ...:         return list(set(l1.split(',')) & set(l2.split(',')))
     ...:

In [111]: checkio("hello,world", "Hello,earth")
Out[111]: []

In [112]: checkio("hello,world", "Hello,earth", case_insensitive=True)
Out[112]: ['hello']
```